# Webview Android 4.0 video Auto Start

Tags: android, html5-video, android-webview

Why my video dosen't start automaticaly,
I'm using a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 10.1 and no video attribute seem to works.

As you can see, I put nothing in the controls, I still have the play button. 
The autoplay is properly set but the video don't start by himself.

Any Idea ?

```
    <video  id="myvideo" width="800px" height="250px"  autoplay="autoplay" controls   >
      <source src="/public/files/vide1.mp4" type="video/mp4"  />
    </video>
```